# UITableViewCell drop event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

whether there are any event from which I handle the drop event of UITableViewCell.

Basically I want to do some task when I drop some thing on a cell of UITableView. So i want to know that whether any event is exist for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a touchUpInside event to the uitableview? Or adding an invisible view, which catches the touch events, on top of the place where you want to catch the drop?

Comment: hi Thomas,
can you describle little more? There are multiple UITableViewCell in UITableView. and for each row, I want to perform different task

Comment: Yes, of course. If you start the drop outside the UITableViewCell, I don't actually know if you can catch the events inside the cell.

Write a class that inherits UITableViewCell and use that custom class when creating the cells. Remember to implement, - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event in your custom class, to try if it works.

Comment: Thanks Tuomas
I will apply this thing and reply you to tomorrow